# How to perform semi join with multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have these two data frames:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'grp':[1,1,2], 'x':[6,4,2], 'y':[7,8,9]})
>>> df1
   grp  x  y
0    1  6  7
1    1  4  8
2    2  2  9
```

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'grp':[1], 'x':[6], 'z':[3]})
>>> df2
   grp  x z
0    1  6 3
```

I figured that a semi-join can be done easily with a single column e.g.

```
>>> df1[df1.grp.isin(df2.grp)]
   grp  x  y
0    1  6  7
1    1  4  8
```

The question is: how do I do that with two columns - `grp` and `x`?

Comment: for inner join : `df1.merge(df2,on=['grp','x'])` ? or `df1.merge(df2,on=['grp','x'],how='left')`

Comment: Semi join should give me all rows from `df1` where `(grp,x)` exists in `df2`. The `merge` function doesn't work because it brings in columns from both data frames. I could do a right join but then I have to drop all the columns from `df2` afterwards...

Comment: Actually you dont have to with a little helper function called `reindex`: `df1.merge(df2,on=['grp','x']).reindex(df1.columns,axis=1)` or `df1.merge(df2,on=['grp','x'],how='right').reindex(df2.columns,axis=1)` for right join but you get the idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `tuple` and you can still with `isin`

```
df1[df1[['grp','x']].agg(tuple,1).isin(df2[['grp','x']].agg(tuple,1))]
Out[205]: 
   grp  x  y
0    1  6  7
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, but quite expensive if df2 has many rows. In that case I would rather use `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that `df2` has many rows, using `isin` will become very expensive. In that case consider using `merge`. An inner join will behave just like a semi join, if the right `DataFrame` consists only of the key columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'grp':[1,1,2], 'x':[6,4,2], 'y':[7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'grp':[1], 'x':[6], 'z':[3]})
df1.merge(df2[['grp', 'x']], how="inner", on=['grp', 'x'])
```